# UITableView with embed UICollectionView is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView with 4 UITableViewCell inside. I want it to be dynamic by setting:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

For the third cell, with embed UICollectionView, it has 20 UICollectionViewCell.

When i run my project, the uicollectionviewcell return (44, 44) and it display these error:

```
The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fe028c25bd0>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fe029884800; frame = (20 0; 335 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000024bbb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000002269c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 44}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fe028c25bd0>.
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

[image]

Thanks in advances.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Well the debugger is telling you what is wrong:

> frame = (20 0; 335 44)

This is your collectionView frame and this means the height of the collectionView is only 44px, which is also the height of your cell. So it doesn't fit in the collectionView with the cell inset values...

Check your collectionView frame and autoLayout constraints

Answer (score 0):

Increase height of your collection view or decrease height of your cell of your collection view because your collection view's height is `44` and cell's height is also `44`. your cell's or item's height must be less then collection view's height!!